# how do I get notified when an in app purchase is performed in android app?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

As I am reading on for in app purchases on amazon, it does provide an intent filter for receiving the purchasing event. I would does google play have similar method for notifying when a purchase is performed or completed?

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/reference/google-to-iap.html

```
<receiver android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.ResponseReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                    android:permission = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start a purchase flow, you pass it an `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` object that you implement. That object receives the call-back when the purchase flow completes, with data indicating whether it succeeded and what (if anything) was purchased. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html) for a description of how Google's purchase flow works.

Note that Google's in-app billing API is considerably different from Amazon's. You don't declare a broadcast receiver in the manifest when using Google's in-app billing.